# Ajax call doesnt work in asp.mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have got this method in my controller.

```
 public string GetTime(string zone)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(offsets[zone]);
        return string.Format("<div>The time in {0} is {1:h:MM:ss tt}</div>", zone.ToUpper(), time);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, int> offsets = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "utc", 0 }, { "bst", 1 }, { "mdt", -6 }};
```

This is my html:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Statistics";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Statistics</h2>
    <h2>
        What time is it?</h2>
    <p>
        Show me the time in:<br />
        @Ajax.ActionLink("UTC", "GetTime", new { zone = "utc" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" })<br />
        @Ajax.ActionLink("BST", "GetTime", new { zone = "bst" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" })
        <br />
        @Ajax.ActionLink("MDT", "GetTime", new { zone = "mdt" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" })
        <br />
    </p>
    <div id="myResults" style="border: 2px dotted red; padding: .5em;">
        Results will appear here
    </div>
    <p>
        This page was generated at @DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("h:MM:ss tt") (UTC)
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the time doesnt appear in the div element..but the time presented on a blank page (meaning there is a postback instead of an ajax call). Why does that happen?

This is how the html of the links loaded look like:

```
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: May be you'll try to use `ActionResult` as a return type and get value as `return Content("Whatever string");`.

Comment: i dont think it is relevant at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included a Layout but in your view, you have an entire `<html>` document and I suppose that you end up with some very broken HTML at the end.

Here's how your view could look like if you don't want to use a layout:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Statistics";
    // Explicitly specify that we don't use any layout because
    // this view already contains the entire html document
    Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Statistics</h2>
    <h2>
        What time is it?</h2>
    <p>
        Show me the time in:<br />
        @Ajax.ActionLink("UTC", "GetTime", new { zone = "utc" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" })<br />
        @Ajax.ActionLink("BST", "GetTime", new { zone = "bst" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" })
        <br />
        @Ajax.ActionLink("MDT", "GetTime", new { zone = "mdt" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" })
        <br />
    </p>
    <div id="myResults" style="border: 2px dotted red; padding: .5em;">
        Results will appear here
    </div>
    <p>
        This page was generated at @DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("h:MM:ss tt") (UTC)
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The only scripts you need is `jquery` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax`. Also don't use any `runat="server"` attributes in razor.

and if you want to use the layout:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Statistics";
}

<h2>
    Statistics</h2>
<h2>
    What time is it?</h2>
<p>
    Show me the time in:<br />
    @Ajax.ActionLink("UTC", "GetTime", new { zone = "utc" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" })<br />
    @Ajax.ActionLink("BST", "GetTime", new { zone = "bst" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" })
    <br />
    @Ajax.ActionLink("MDT", "GetTime", new { zone = "mdt" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myResults" })
    <br />
</p>
<div id="myResults" style="border: 2px dotted red; padding: .5em;">
    Results will appear here
</div>
<p>
    This page was generated at @DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("h:MM:ss tt") (UTC)
</p>
```

Once again don't forget the 2 scripts in your layout.

And a final remark: by convention all controller actions should return ActionResults, so:

```
public string GetTime(string zone)
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(offsets[zone]);
    return Content(string.Format("<div>The time in {0} is {1:h:MM:ss tt}</div>", zone.ToUpper(), time));
}
```

Finally make sure you don't use any `Microsoft*.js` script in your pages. Those are obsolete.

Comment: Thanks.Darin, This forum is lucky to have you. One more question. I do have a master page...And I defined the title twice (visual studio tells me to). What if i want to override the masterpages title attribute. What would i do then?

Comment: @BlackFire27, in your layout: `<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>` and in your view: `@{ ViewBag.Title = "Statistics"; }`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't included your unobstrusive Jquery file.

Add this to your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
```

Comment: have you checked that this file has been loaded? your problem looks like the behaviour when the ajax eventhandler is not attached to the link (this is usually what prevents you to switch to the url, thats a fallback behaviour if someone has JS disabled - btw: you haven't js disabled?)

Comment: no..it is enabled..i use chrome. youtube/google work..so my code should. How can i check if my file was loaded? SEE UPDATE

Comment: Is it setting as UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = "true" in web.config?

Comment: @BlackFire27 And don't see referencing jquery script in your html file.